# Facebook is causing my activity to leak

Tags: android, leakcanary

I'm using `LeakCanary` version 1.4-beta2 and I have just added Facebook sdk in my app. More precisely I have only added in MyApplication class this code in `onCreate` :

```
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

Yet I get this error from `LeakCanary` :

```
In css.demo.debug:1.0:1.
* css.demo.main.projects.ProjectsActivity has leaked:
* GC ROOT static com.facebook.appevents.internal.ActivityLifecycleTracker.currentFuture
* references java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.callable   * references java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.task
* references com.facebook.appevents.internal.ActivityLifecycleTracker$4$1.this$0 (anonymous implementation of java.lang.Runnable)
* references com.facebook.appevents.internal.ActivityLifecycleTracker$4.val$activity (anonymous implementation of java.lang.Runnable)
* leaks css.demo.main.projects.ProjectsActivity instance
```

How should I deal with this problem ? Is there a problem somewhere in my code and I should investigate more or it has something to do with Facebook/LeakCanary code and I should file an issue?

Comment: Same, did you find any solution so far ?

Comment: @limon iirc it was Facebook's problem and when you update sdk version you get rid of it